# Why i cant use commands and events in same code in python to make Discord bot

Tags: python

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():     #tells  me if bot is ready
    print("Bot je spreman")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):  #Bot says hi to member in her dm
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f"Bok{member.name}, dobrodošao")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):    # Ignore messages made by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    odgovori = ["Dobro sam","Lose sam","OK sam"]

    if message.content == "Kako si":   #Bot responds to message(When i put this block in my code my commands wont work. How do i fix this?)
        odg = random.choice(odgovori)
        await message.channel.send(odg)
        await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command(aliases=["kick"])     #Bot kick people from server
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def k(ctx,member : discord.Member,*,reason= "Bez razloga"):
    await member.send("Izbacen si sa servera, zbog"+reason)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)

@client.command(aliases=["clear"])     #Bot deletes messages
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
async def c(ctx,kolicina=2):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit= kolicina)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):            #Bot shows ping
    await ctx.send(f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Some thing in code are in croatian laungauge like "odgovori" and some strings. I am new to coding and Im sorry if smthing triigers you.............................................................................................................................

Comment: You need to unindent your `client.process_commands(message)` by one layer. It is currently only being executed when the message reads `Kako si`. Put it on the same indentation level as the `if`-block it currently is in and the bot will respond to commands

Comment: I just realised that ,I was looking code for 15 mins and I didnt saw it. Ty sm.